# MySQL Query Shows Inconsistent Result Every time

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT pv.product_variation_key,
                p.product_key,
                p.brand_key,
                p.name,
                p.vehicle_type,
                p.short_description,
                pp.medium_image,
                b.brand_name,
                b.big_image,
                ts.tire_size,
                pv.sku,
                pv.price,
                pv.dealer_price,
                pv.retail_price,
                pv.weight,
                pv.width,
                pv.performance_rating,
                pv.mileage_warranty,
                pv.overall_diameter,
                pv.tread_depth,
                pv.maximum_psi,
                vte.road_hazard,
                vte.road_hazard_price,
                vte.load_index,
                vte.sidewall,
                vte.UTQG,
                vte.load_ply_rating,
                vte.load_range,
                tsr.tire_speed_rating,
                cr.rating,
                IF(pv.sku != i.sku,'true','false'),
                ROUND((((acos(sin((41.3309413*pi()/180)) * sin((sc.latitude*pi()/180)) + cos((41.3309413*pi()/180)) * cos((sc.latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((abs(-75.7429636 - sc.longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) , 1) AS distance
FROM (products p,
      product_variations pv,
      brands b,
      tire_sizes ts,
      variation_tire_size_applications vts,
      variation_tire_extradatas vte,
      inventorys i,
      supply_chain_centers sc)
LEFT JOIN customer_reviews cr ON cr.product_key = p.product_key
AND cr.is_approved = 'yes'
LEFT JOIN variation_tire_speed_rating_applications vtsra ON vtsra.product_variation_key = pv.product_variation_key
LEFT JOIN tire_speed_ratings tsr ON vtsra.tire_speed_rating_key = tsr.tire_speed_rating_key
LEFT JOIN product_photos pp ON p.product_key = pp.product_key
AND pp.photo_type= 'default image'
WHERE pv.product_key = p.product_key
  AND p.status = 'active'
  AND b.brand_key = p.brand_key
  AND pv.product_variation_key = vts.product_variation_key
  AND ts.tire_size_key = vts.tire_size_key
  AND pv.product_variation_key = vte.product_variation_key
  AND i.supply_chain_center_key = sc.supply_chain_center_key
  AND i.brand_key = p.brand_key
  AND sc.status = 'Active'
  AND pv.sku=i.sku
  AND i.current_stock > 0
  AND (p.name LIKE '%win%'
       OR pv.variation_name LIKE '%win%'
       OR p.product_type LIKE '%win%'
       OR b.brand_name LIKE '%win%'
       OR LCASE(pv.sku) LIKE '%win%')
GROUP BY pv.product_variation_key
HAVING (distance <= 1000)
ORDER BY pv.retail_price ASC,
         cr.rating DESC,
         p.name ASC
```

I have facing issue with MySQL query its shows inconsistent result every time in phpmyadmin i think this issue happens because of latitude and longitude. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You should re-format and indent your SQL query. Not sure if somebody helps you.

Comment: Especially with that 1993-character query

Comment: @Pritam can you show us an example of two different result sets?

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule when using `GROUP BY`:

> Every column in the `SELECT` clause must be in the `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function must be applied to it!

If this is not the case, a random row out of each group is displayed. MySQL is to my knowledge the only DBMS that allows this, but always remember, it's wrong. You can also disable this by setting the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Comment: This is correct I've come across the same issue before as @fancyPants says other DBMS like PostgreSQL force you to specify all columns in the GROUP BY to ensure nothing is random.